# Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/x-js // Warnings recurrent in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

This warning/error keeps on coming in the Console of Chrome when I run my site.

```
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/x-js
```

I tried adding this to my script tag, but it gives no love!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand. Did you mean the source of the error?

Comment: No I mean the `src` attribute of the problem tag

Answer (score 1):

- enter regedit.exe
- find the .js folder in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT
- right click 'content type'
- modify the value data to 'text/javascript', not 'text/plain'